# I want to use a websocket API with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket, signalr

My question is how to use a websocket API. I get some information from the company which websocket API I want to use. But I don't understand it completly.
I got an Js file back and an word document. I am currently devoloping in JS I want to use their websocket API for realtime chart-data.

> The path to the socket is https://www.bittrex.com/signalR.  To connect to the generated proxy include the following references in your code:
>
> ```
> <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
> <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
> <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
> ```

My first question is what is signalr/hubs?

My second questions is I download the SignalR-2.1.0.min-js file from [here](http://www.bootcdn.cn/signalr.js/) I don't know if that is correct. Becuase I didn't find any other files.

My 3 question is when I there app.js file to my document like this:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

I get this error's in my console of my browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function
    at r.fn.init.r.fn.load (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4)
    at jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js:11
    at jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js:11 app.js:3 
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
        at app.js:3
```

This is written at line 3 of app.js:

```
var signalR = require("signalr-client");
```

Does someone can explain to my what I need to do?

Comment: 1. You can read about signalR [here](https://www.asp.net/signalr).  2. If you are unsure, you can get the correct signalR JS library from Nuget or [Git](https://github.com/signalr/signalr). 3. *It seems* you need to import a library called require.JS.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I didn't know I need an other JS libary. I will try it out!